# PHP: Loging into remote site with curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to login to this site with php curl but it doesn't work?!

site: http://ks.kunskapsporten.se

I think it might be because it redirects you like 3 times before you come to the login screen.

This is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sts.kunskapsskolan.se/adfs/ls/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "UserName=MahUsar&Password=MahPass&AuthMethod=FormsAuthentication"); (Unsure about the auth thing)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: You're not posting to the right url, you should check the `action` attribute of the form...

Comment: You can add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); to follow redirects.

Comment: @jeroen i have fixed that but it still does not work :/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with the Firefox debugger and the webs seems to be posting the login details to

```
https://sts.kunskapsskolan.se/adfs/ls/
```

And there three fields:

```
UserName: aaa@bbb.ccc
Password: 123456
AuthMethod: FormsAuthentication
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$username = 'myuser';
$password = 'mypass';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sts.kunskapsskolan.se/adfs/ls/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'UserName='.$username.'&Password='.$password);

curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: No, it just returns a page saying something went wrong :/